# Create multidimentional array from SQL table

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a table 'GOAL':

```
    ID   TYPE   KEY     VALUE
    --   ----   ---     -----
    1    RED    BASE    3
    2    BLUE   NAME    ALLOR
    3    RED    MAIN    _TTR
    4    GREEN  LOCAL   PIN,SEC,BALL,UNI
    5    BLUE   ALT     2DFFRST34@HH&FR#
    6    GREEN  DOMAIN  SITE.ORG,NSPL.EDU,ROAR.IN
```

I want to create a multidimentional array in PHP which will produce this array:

```
    $GOAL = array (
        'RED'  => array    (
               'BASE' => 3,
               'MAIN' => '_TTR'
        ),
        'BLUE'   => array(
               'NAME' => 'ALLOR',
               'ALT' => '2DFFRST34@HH&FR#'
        ),
        'GREEN'   => array(
               'LOCAL' => 'PIN,SEC,BALL,UNI',
               'DOMAIN' => 'SITE.ORG,NSPL.EDU,ROAR.IN'
        )
    );
```

What should be the query?

Comment: I recommend you read up on `JOIN`s and learn how to sort through an array. Or consider serializing your data in JSON and then storing that.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. What have you tried so far, and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someting like this should work

```
  <?php 
        $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM GOAL');
        $goal = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            if(!isset($goal[$row->type])) {
                $goal[$row->type] = array();
            }
            $goal[$row->type][$row->key] = $row->value;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Farla, it worked for obvious. @DiMono: I'm new to it and was confused to construct this. The table is a similar dummy of some other table, for example.